# How to register a custom component as valid, invalid, dirty, touched etc

Tags: angular

How can I register a component that implements ControlValueAccessor as touched, dirty, valid etc

```
export class InputDropdownComponent implements ControlValueAccessor
```

I need to write validation logic in the template for a custom component:

```
<div *ngIf="form.get('amount').hasError('outOfRange') && form.get('amount').touched"
     class="validation-error">
        The amount is out of range, minimum = ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

ngControl has functions to set form attribute:

```
this.ngControl.control.markAsTouched();
this.ngControl.control.markAsDirty()
this.ngControl.control.markAsPristine()
```

To use `ngControl`:

```
import { NgControl } from "@angular/forms";
import { Injector } from "@angular/core";

constructor(private el: ElementRef, private inj: Injector) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.ngControl = this.inj.get(NgControl);
}
```